# Integer sets with forbidden differences

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

Given a finite set $S$ of positive integers, and a positive integer $n$, let $F(n,S)$ be the largest possible cardinality of a subset of {$1,2,\dots,n$} no two of whose elements differ by a number in $S$.

E.g., if $S=${$2,3$} and $n=10$, we have $F(n,S)=4$ corresponding for instance to the set {$1,2,6,7$}.

What is known about the computational complexity of $F$?

A purely greedy approach doesn't work. E.g., if $S=${$3,5$} and $n=20$, a greedy approach gives the set {$1,2,3,9,10,11,17,18,19$} which has smaller cardinality than {$1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19$}.

Dynamic programming works, but takes computational resources that are exponential in max($S$). Can one do better?

I don't like the name of this question; if anyone can think of a better way to describe the problem, please feel free to revise it.

Comment: Perhaps "Picking many integer points in $1$-dimensional lattice-polytope, while avoiding certain distances"

Comment: Or: "Integer sets with forbidden differences."

Comment: What if instead of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we can only select elements from some $X$ subset of it (that is given as part of the input)? There is a better chance for hardness results maybe. And of course you must know, but let me also mention that if $S$ has only odd integers, then the graph is bipartite and thus we can solve the problem in polynomial time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to view this problem:

Form the graph $G$ with vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and edges $(i,j)$ for all $i,j$ such that $|i-j|\in S$. Then $F(n,S)$ is the size of a maximal independent set in $G$.

From this it is clear $F$ has at most the computational complexity of finding the size of a maximal independent set. It is not quite clear to me how to use the special properties of this graph to get something better.

For special sets $S$, one immediately gets the value $F(n,S)$:

- $F(n,\{k\})=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\lfloor\frac{n+k+i-1}{2k}\rfloor$
- $F(n,\{1,\dots,k\})=\lceil\frac{n}{k+1}\rceil$

For your two examples the graphs look like this:

[image: n=10, S=(2,3)]
[image: n=20, S=(3,5)].

All instances for $F(10,\{2,3\})=4$ are:

> $\{1, 2, 6, 7\}, \{1, 2, 6, 10\}, \{1, 2, 7, 8\}, \{1, 2, 8, 9\}, \{1, 2, 9, 10\}, \{1, 5, 6, 10\}, \{1, 5, 9, 10\}, \{2, 3, 7, 8\}, \{2, 3, 8, 9\}, \{2, 3, 9, 10\}, \{3, 4, 8, 9\}, \{3, 4, 9, 10\}, \{4, 5, 9, 10\}$

All instances for $F(20,\{3,5\})=10$ are:

> $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19\}, \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20\}$

Comment: this was answered before the question was edited to be more specific